# 'TFLiteKerasModelConverterV2' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, data-science, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to predict values by loading a saved version of my model.
here is the code for it-

```
def classifier(img, weights_file):
    # Load the model

    model = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(weights_file)

    # Create the array of the right shape to feed into the keras model
    data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 200, 200, 3), dtype=np.float32)
    image = img
    # image sizing
    size = (200, 200)
    image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

    # turn the image into a numpy array
    image_array = np.asarray(image)
    # Normalize the image
    normalized_image_array = image_array.astype(np.float32) / 255

    # Load the image into the array
    data[0] = normalized_image_array

    # run the inference
    prediction_percentage = model.predict(data)
    prediction = prediction_percentage.round()

    return prediction, prediction_percentage
```

My model throws an error " 'TFLiteKerasModelConverterV2' object has no attribute 'predict'"
Can anyone please tell me what can i change here?

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a TFLiteConverter object from your weights file. The correct way to load the model weights is using `load_weights` [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#load_weights). Try:

```py
tf.keras.model.load_weights(weights_file)
```

However, you also would first need to define the model the same way as you did when training the model. If you have saved your model in `SavedModel` format, use

```py
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(weights_file)
```